# Dax Measure not calculating totals correctly

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Can you please assist i have a Dax Measure that i use to count distinct numbers in a column ,but the issue is its not calculating the totals and the rows correctly (as per Pic ),please assist i have also added the code  [image]

```
Total Lines = 
VAR _LessSky =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(ContractSales[SecondaryMSISDN]),FILTER(DimInvoiceType,
        DimInvoiceType[InvoiceType]  <> "Credit Note"),
        ContractSales[Price Plan] <> "Sky Package"
    )

VAR _SkyP =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(ContractSales[PrimaryMSISDN]),
        FILTER(DimInvoiceType,
        DimInvoiceType[InvoiceType]  <> "Credit Note"),
        ContractSales[Price Plan] = "Sky Package"
    )

RETURN
    _LessSky + _SkyP
```

can you please assist in showing what am i doing incorrectly

Comment: It is calculating it correctly. `DISTINCTCOUNT` is by definition a semi-additive aggregation. If you want to turn it into an additive aggregation you need to wrap it in `SUMX`.